# Deleting the last row in a table. SQL/Netbeans

Tags: sql, netbeans

In java, i am trying to delete the last row of my database. The database has 15 rows and i want to the delete the 15th one. The columns are called Initials and Score.

```
                 Intials         Scores
   rows# 1.         ADS          2343
         2.         DDE          5454      
        15.         TBK           332
```

I can't have it selecting TBK because i'm wanting it to delete the 15th one no matter what it is so a new one can be added. Everywhere I've looked it's always has to be specific or a delete all rows. Can anyone help? Many thanks to those who help. :)

Comment: how do you decide which row you want to delete?

Comment: 15th implies an order. Which column are you ordering your rows by when you say 15th?

Comment: There are 2 columns: Intials and score. There are 15 rows. each one having a initials and a score, i want to delete the last one without having to select it by whatever is in it. This is a example of what i DON'T want:DELETE FROM HiScores
WHERE Intials='TBK' AND Score='332';

Comment: There is no such thing as "the last row" in a relational table. Rows in a relational database are ***NOT*** sorted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> OP : I am trying to delete **the last row** of my database.

- make resultset updatable : `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);`
- set cursor to last record : `resultSet.last();`
- delete last Record : `resultSet.deleteRow();`
- for further use of `rs` you should set : `resultSet.beforeFirst();`

---

```
private static int delLastRow(ResultSet resultSet) {
    if (resultSet == null) {
        return 0;
    }
    try {
        resultSet.last();
        int delID = resultSet.getInt(1);
        resultSet.deleteRow();
        System.out.println("Deleted id :" + delID);
        resultSet.beforeFirst();
        return delID;
    } catch (SQLException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultSet.beforeFirst();
        } catch (SQLException exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}   

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
      stmt = conn.createStatement(
              ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
              ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
      //rs will be scrollable, will not show changes made by others,
      //and will be updatable

      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT * FROM `order details`";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
      System.out.println("Deleted id :"+ delLastRow(rs));
      ....
  }
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @moskito-x, Steve, and Minh. i got it working now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming id is an identity column

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM table)
```

Comment: He doesn't need to delete a column, just the row, so it would just be `DELETE FROM...`

Comment: The code works but also doesn't work. I'm attempting to delete the 15th one, write to the database(i haven't done this yet so i'll hit that sped bump when i get to it), and then read the database. when i put   ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( SQL );
             stmt.execute(deleteTableSQL);, it will show the database, but delete a random one instead of the 15th. but if i put it in backwards it will delete the 15th one but it won't show the database.